# Manually Changing Orientation of UIViewController ? iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to manually set a view controller's orientation (in this case back to its initial position) ?

Thank you.

Comment: its possible but you really shouldnt!!

Comment: There's a good reason - how could I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
                            animated:YES];
```